# VW and VH units are not accurate

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

```
width: 100vw;/* 100% of viewport width */
height: 100vh;/* 100% of viewport height*/
```

This CSS should give me the exact(100%) dimensions of the viewport. But it is apparently too large because it's causing an overflow on the page.

It is not padding, margin, or outline because I removed all of that.

*note* It also seems that it only "grows" bigger than the projected dimensions when I add two divs with these dimensions. *(but it's always the case in jsfiddle)*

http://jsfiddle.net/0psu7ys6/

Should I just consider it a bug and write a work around? Or am I missing something?

Comment: add `overflow:hidden` to the parent element (in this case the `<body>` tag) should solve it so you can keep all the rest as is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The viewport measurements are accurate. The problem lies in the fact that your div is an inline-block. The browser renders your inline-block element on a line box. The whitespace underneath your div comes from the baseline of this line box; it is the area where typographic descenders should go. This additional space, combined with your div, is what results in overflow.

If you remove the `display: inline-block` declaration so that your div is rendered as a block-level element, the scrollbars will go away and the div will fit the viewport exactly.

If you need this element to be an inline-block for some reason, setting `vertical-align: top` (or `bottom` or `middle`) seems to fix it.

Comment: Is there anyway to get rid of it? And it probably isn't necessary since I do have it at 100% ... But that is a unfortunate thing to hear.

Comment: Also, if you do remove the inline-block but add another div it does the same thing again. Notice: http://jsfiddle.net/0psu7ys6/4/

Comment: Change it to `display: block` and it disappears. If you need it to be inline-block and have zero letter spacing then you need to set the font-size to 0 on the parent. You'll most likely wanna set it back to something readable in each child.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew: That is because you now have two elements with height equal to the viewport height, for a total of 200% of the viewport height.

Comment: @BoltClock Because they're equal to the height of the page there is an overflow in the *horizontal* dimension? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew: Oh, *that* is because of the vertical scrollbar. The presence of a scrollbar doesn't affect vw/vh calculations, so you end up having overflow in both directions.

Comment: @BoltClock okay thanks, I think I'm just going to use percentages since that seems to be less buggy..

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew: Yeah - percentage measurements will adjust for scrollbars. Viewport measurements will not.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve this

you should set the `line-height` of all the body in `vh`